# Facebook Litho: Visible Event hasn't triggered when fragment resumed

Tags: litho, facebook-litho

Visible Event hasn't triggered when fragment resumed.
 I also tried to call `LithoView.setVisibilityHint(true);` on fragment resume but it doesn't work to trigger the visible event of the Component.
 However, it will be triggered successfully when scrolling up / down to show the component view in the RecyclerCollectionComponent.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a known problem right now. If you call `LithoView#setVisibilityHint(true)` on resume, you will have also needed to call `LithoView.setVisibilityHint(false)` in pause: in that case, you should get invisibility and visibility callbacks when you pause and resume, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I want to have more flexibility to update the state of litho components inside recyclercollectioncomponent in the fragment or activity. Do you have good practices to do so?

Comment: The recommended way would be to do this via props if at all possible as it will help achieve a simpler one-way data flow. If that's not possible, you can set a listener within the component if necessary from `onCreateInitialState`. There's currently not a good reciprocal lifecycle method to `onCreateInitialState` (i.e. an `onDestroy`), so keep that in mind -- hopefully one will be added soon :)

Comment: I think adding a listener as prop to component is not a good practice. Actually, I asked the contributors for this question but no response. Thanks for your help. Foxichu

Comment: I did not mean adding a listener as a prop, they are two different suggestions :) :

1. Whenever you want to update state based on external events (e.g. from Fragments or Activitys), try to structure as a prop change instead and call setRootAsync. This is the best choice for now if it's possible.
2. Alternately, if this is not possible for some reason, you can set a listener from inside the component, but there are the lifecycle issues I mentioned above